# Is isotropy preserved under uniaxial compression?

Tags: geometry

First consider a cube which contains an isotropic distribution of point particles.  The cube has sides of length 1,1,1 parallel to the (Cartesian, orthogonal) x,y and z axes.

Next the cube is "compressed" along the z-axis so that the z-coordinate of any point particle becomes z/4.  This produces a rectangular block or slab which has sides of length 1, 1, 0.25.  The point particles are not distorted by the compression.

Finally four such slabs are stacked one on top of the other in the z-direction so as to produce a new cube with sides of length 1,1,1.

Is the distribution of point particles in the new cube isotropic?

Comment: Depends on the distribution. If the points were drawn from a Poisson process (i.e. each point independently of the others) then yes. In general no. For example, if the points were drawn from a blue-noise process (each point at least a certain distance away from all others) then this property will no longer hold afterwards.

Comment: @Rahul. Thanks. I am interested in the first case (Poisson Process). I can see that (taken after the compression) a standard cylindrical sample volume would contain the same number of point particles if it was aligned with the x,y or z axis.